# How to install Beta Version of Jetpack Compose in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack

sorry if this question is not smart, I'm complete new to Android Studio. How can you install the beta version of Jetpack Compose in your App? Thanks for your answers.

Boothosh

Comment: check https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/documentation

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup

Also, make sure you're using the Canary version of Android Studio, which can be downloaded here: https://developer.android.com/studio/preview